# Unable to import plotly into Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, plotly, jupyter

I am new to Python and I installed plotly library using Anaconda prompt using command `pip install plotly` and it shows it to be installed under libraries installed but doesn't get imported when I try to import via the Jupyter Library saying the module is not found.

Comment: Related: [How to install 'plotly' from inside Anaconda under Colab on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60808369/how-to-install-plotly-from-inside-anaconda-under-colab-on-mac)

Answer (score 3):

This is typically due to multiple Python interpreters being installed, so the Python you see in the notebook is probably not the Python you used to install plotly.

You can check this by looking at `sys.executable` and `sys.path`, and comparing those with `where pip` in the Anaconda prompt where you ran `pip install plotly`.

You can make sure to use the right Python by doing:

```
C:\full\path\to\right\python.exe -m pip install plotly
```

This should be the same as `sys.executable` in your notebook.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue.
Go to Anaconda prompt and type `pip install plotly` hit enter. Restart the kernel and try importing it again.

Answer (score 0):

Going further feom @minrk answer:

After a while searching about this problem, I discovered it is a broken conda-kernel trough jupyter notebook issue.

Inside your notebook **check if it is pointing to the write python executable's envinronment path** by using minrk solution:

```
import sys
sys.executable 

# >>>> 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\**wrong_env**\\python.exe'
```

**If it isn't**, the simple solution is to `install nb_conda`:

```
conda install nb_conda
```