# How to install 'plotly' from inside Anaconda under Colab on Mac

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, google-colaboratory

I tried to import `plotly` in `Anaconda` with code

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly import __version__
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```

but received error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-978bd9a5088a> in <module>
     14 
     15 # import plotly.plotly as py
---> 16 import plotly.graph_objs as go
     17 from plotly import __version__
     18 from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'
```

I have checked a number of similar posts to install `'plotly'` on `Jupyter` but somehow I couldn't do it on Mac. I usually use Google Colab, could it be the reason that I am using different platforms that caused the confusion when installing?

Comment: Are you looking for solutions from inside jupyter under Colab, or from the Mac command-line, or both? And all of these with Anaconda as the environment manager.

Comment: @smci I am not sure if we could do it from inside jupyter under Colab. I would like to download the outputs as HTML from jupyter, since I was using Colab which didn't have this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jupyter Notebooks start in an "environment". Anaconda created the environment and it contains a lot of useful libraries. It also holds a self-contained python interpreter. In this instance, the environment didn't have the library plotly installed (it's not a default library that Anaconda provides) so you had to install plotly in your environment that the notebook lives in.

The environments that are used with Jupyter Notebooks are a little tricky to get to in order to install things, so this way, using `import sys` then installing the library with `!{sys.executable} -m pip install plotly` finds the python interpreter with `!{sys.executable}` and installs plotly using pip right in the Notebook itself.

More reading:

- [Environments](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/)
- [Pip](https://realpython.com/what-is-pip/)
- [Packages included with Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/old-pkg-lists/4.3.1/py35/)

try:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly import __version__
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```

Comment: It worked, thank you. Could you please briefly explain what gives rise to the issue?

Comment: Sure. I added some commentary to the post.

Comment: The commentary is very helpful. It's amazing how you made abstract concepts easy to understand. Much appreciate the reading materials. Thank you Ollie.

Comment: You could also avoid the ``sys.executable`` logic and use [``%pip install``](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-pip) directly (note the ``%``), and it will install the package with the correct executable.